# Office 2013 First Time Run video plays every time

Tags: microsoft-office, group-policy, microsoft-office-2013

I have a user running Office 2013 (32-bit) on Windows 7 Professional (SP1). Every time they open an Office application, they get shown the First Run video. Office is fully updated, and I have run a "repair installation" on the Office installation.

The First Run video should also in theory be disabled by group policy as I've set the appropriate policies (software\policies\microsoft\office\15.0\firstrun\bootedrtm and software\policies\microsoft\office\15.0\firstrun\disablemovie are both showing 1 on a gpresult check).

It only affects this user - other users logging in to the same machine do not get the same treatment.

Is there anything I'm missing that might be triggering the movie to run every time the applications are launched?

Comment: For anyone who experiences the same - the cause was the Group Policy, though I'm not currently sure why. Disabling the group policy stopped the error. I am planning on re-downloading the ADMX files and re-applying the group policy to see if this resolves the issue.